# Azure Mobile Sync with an existing API

Tags: azure, mobile, xamarin, azure-mobile-services, offlineapps

I'm looking at using the Azure Mobile Sync offline functionality in Xamarin. The functionality is exactly what we are looking for, but I don't want to connect directly to my database tables because I can't define that in code in a Mobile Azure App (as far as I'm aware), and I already have a perfectly good API that deals with all my business logic.

Has anyone managed to connect the offline sync with an existing API without using the Azure Mobile App?

My other alternative here is to create the Azure Mobile App and create methods within it that will connect directly to my API from there, essentially creating a proxy, but I feel that might be more complex than it needs to be. Does anyone have any opinion on this?

I'll need to find a way of passing my API token through as well, but that's a question for another day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a Domain Manager (ASP.NET, based on the IDomainManager interface) or a Data Provider (Node.js) that implements your API.  We have not documented either interface very well, but there are plenty of examples within the server SDK repos on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, you are a good guy to know, I found your blog here. https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/domainmgr/ - if you have any good examples I'd be keen to take a look

Comment: On https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server - take a look at the TableStorage domain manager here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/tree/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Storage